# Square Roots by Newton's Method (SCIP example 1.1.7) in R code

Tags: r, sicp

I want to apply Newton's Method for square root through iterations in RStudio, but I keep getting error

> "Error: C stack usage  7969204 is too close to the limit"

when I put a wrong sqrt in the 'g'. Instead, the code works fine when I write directly the right number (example: sqriter(2,4) --> 2)

Below is the code I wrote for it.

thank you for your help!

```
sqriter <- function(g,x){
  ifelse(goodguess(g,x), g, sqriter(improve(g,x), x))
}

goodguess <- function(g,x){
  abs(g*g-x)<0.001
}

average <- function(g,x){
  ((g+x)/2)
}

improve <- function(g,x){
  average(g, (g/x))
}
```

Comment: I solved it! I had a mistake in the "improve" function, The correct function is then:  improve <- function(g,x){
  average(g, (x/g))

Comment: here's another way to write the function: sqriter2 <- function(g,x){
  while(abs(g*g-x)>0.001){
  print(g)
  g = improve(g,x)
} }

Comment: You can write it as an answer (instead of comment) if you have solved it yourself.